# Strange file that I can't delete/move/rename

Tags: delete, permanent-delete

The name of this file is: `Soldier Project. blend@`

I can't delete it, move it, or even rename the thing. I was using Blend to make a rig for a soldier, hence the name, when I rage quited out of frustration. I closed the program and noticed it was there and decided to delete it because I didn't want it clogging up my desktop but then I got this message:

```
Error when getting information for file '/home/user/Desktop/Soldier Project.blend@': No such file or directory
```

Every time I try to do something with the file that pops up. I don't know what it means or what it is, can you please help me?

Comment: Can you try pressing ctrl-r at the desktop? If that doesn't work, have you rebooted? It seems like it might have been deleted already, but your file manager hasn't realised.

Comment: I would try doing `rm -f Soldier\ Project.\ blend\@`

Comment: @MarkYisri I don't think you have escaped all spaces in your command.

Comment: @Bruni thanks, I didn't notice. edited comment

Comment: @J.Sabere that space is the name is not accidental, right ??

Comment: Please use `rm "/home/user/Desktop/Soldier Project.blend@"` (yes, with quotatin marks) and let us know if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -i switch (interactive) on rm:

```
rm -i /Desktop/So*
```

and type y for the question about the file you want to remove.

Garbled filenames may contain non-printing characters, remapped characters (Esc to Dollar for instance), so let the rm command use the actual name, (which gets nicely quoted, in case you want to rename it, you can answer n, then use the quoted name in the mv command).

Still have problems, run fsck for a disk check, and try again.